# fetch other(custom) column with group by and count using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to fetch vacancies from the vacancies table.

**vacancies** table

**id**  |                     **position**

1 | Laravel dev

2 | Php dev

3 | Laravel dev

4 | Laravel dev

5 | Laravel dev

I want to fetch vacancies using some where statement but result should be with count.

[image]

As you can see in above screenshot... I am getting only Position column and Count  for this i am using following query-

```
$vacancies = Vacancy::where('tag_category_id', $TagCatId)
            ->select('position', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('position')
            ->get();
```

What if i want ID column as well in this result?

Comment: If you want to retrieve additional columns, you need to define it in your `select()`. In your particular case, I'd add `id` in there too.

Comment: @Mozammil By doing that throwing an error - http://joxi.ru/12M3VRYcMRJDjr

Comment: You also need  to add id to your groupBy()

Comment: By doing that it fetching rows 2 times .. there are 3 results for this query but by adding Id to groupby it fetches 6 records - http://joxi.ru/nAyde1xUYKnpZ2

Comment: 2 obvious options. 1) Dont group by. You want the ID, so get all the record you want and group them in code, 2) You can group_concat the ids into a single field and get them from that.

Comment: Correct, you can't use this query like that to pull a count when you have a distinct value and a common value in the group by. It will group by the distinct meaning you get a row for each id. I guess you need to ask yourself what you want from the query. The count of job types or each job ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you need to first set `strict` key as **false** in `database.php` in mysql connection

```
 'strict' => false,   //change true to false ..
```

then run this command clear config

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then run this query

```
Vacancy::where('tag_category_id', $TagCatId)
            ->select('id','position', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('position')
            ->get();
```

read more about strict mode [see](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)

if you want to customize in mode you can do that [see](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2/)

> Disabling it wouldn't make your website unsecured if you handle all
>   validations in your controllers and follow best practices like Laravel
>   already does out of the box.

Comment: Doesn't this kill the grouping?

Comment: Yes. This is working. But is there any down side by setting strict = false ?

Comment: @TrueCode i think no any down side otherwise laravel and mysql 5.7 doesn't give this feature..

Answer (score 0):

### Try using the GROUP_CONCAT:

```
$vacancies = Vacancy::where('tag_category_id', $TagCatId)
            ->select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS IDs','position', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('position')
            ->get();
```

This will give you a comma separated list of IDs for each position

I ran this on my users table so ignore the column names but you will get a result in this format:

### My query:

```
Users::select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS IDs'), DB::raw('count(*) as Total'), 'team_id')
->groupBy('team_id')
->get();
```

### My output:

```
App\Users {#3297
         IDs: "9,69,70,72,73",
         Total: 5,
         team_id: 11,
       },
```